# page size of a unix machine using malloc

Tags: unix, malloc, page-size

How do I know page size of a unix machine, using malloc()?

Comment: Why do you need to use malloc()?  Why not use getpagesize()?

Comment: it was asked in interview, so probably they wanted to ask whether I know about what malloc returns and what it actually reserves (maybe a page)

Answer (score 3):

I guess if you allocate a buffer large enough, it'll have to get another few pages and then it'll put the buffer at the start of the first page. So you can allocate two very large buffers, remove the buffer header offset and then GCD the two buffers. Worked out pretty nicely on my system.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
        if (b == 0)
                return a;
        else
                return gcd(b, a % b);
}

void main() {
    void *p1 = malloc(1000000);
    void *p2 = malloc(1000000);
    unsigned p1r = (unsigned) p1 & 0xfffffff0;
    unsigned p2r = (unsigned) p2 & 0xfffffff0;
    printf("page size = %u\n", getpagesize());
    printf("p1 = %p, p2 = %p\n", p1, p2);
    printf("p1r = %p, p2r = %p\n", p1r, p2r);
    printf("gcd = %u\n", gcd(p1r, p2r));
}
```

Comment: Ugly, but it has the hacker nature.

Comment: what's the significance of p1 & 0xfffffff0, why are we masking out last 4 bits?

Comment: Because each allocated buffer has a header associated with it. The structure depends on the implementation of the heap, but there's usually something there. The return value is the allocated memory plus an offset to hide that structure. So to get the beginning of the page, we must ignore that offset.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what malloc has to do with it, however:

```
#include <unistd.h>

(size_t) sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
```